# How to get "Browse" URL for web site in IIS using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

Say, I have the "Site Name" web site in the IIS. I can access most of its functions via the [ServerManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class from my C# code. What I can't seem to figure out is how to get the "Browse" URL for it, like I showed on the screenshot below?

[image]

If I go to Manage Website -> Browse in the *IIS Manager*, it will launch the IE with a URL as such:

```
http://localhost:8080/app1/Default.aspx
```

So I need to get a URL like that.

PS. Note that I don't need to launch the site itself.

Comment: By querying binfings of this site you can get the host name and port number. But you won't get the rest, as the URL you pasted was not the original URL. app1 and Default.aspx come from later redirection and default document expansion usually and you can only get that by launching the site.

Answer (score 1):

Right click and go to `edit bindings...` under `Host Name` you can actually see which domain it is.

Or

Click the site and on actions tab on right hand side you can click `bindings...`

**To Get the URL :**

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
//http://localhost:8080/app1/Default.aspx

HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
// /YourSite/app1/Defaul.aspx

HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
// localhost:8080
```

**Edit:**

To get site information try using `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()` or `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteID()` see below sample(it is not tested) :

```
using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager())
{
    foreach (Binding b in sm.Sites[HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName()].Bindings)
    {
        // ...
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote("localhost"))
{
    int counter = 0;
    string[] ipAddress = new string[10];
    string[] sites = new string[10];
    List<Tuple<string, string>> mylist = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    foreach (var site in sm.Sites)
    {
        sites[counter] = site.Name;

        foreach(var bnd in site.Bindings)
            ipAddress[counter] = bnd.EndPoint != null ? 
                bnd.EndPoint.Address.ToString() : String.Empty;

        mylist.Add(Tuple.Create(sites[counter], ipAddress[counter]));
                counter++;                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this "foreach(var bnd in site.Bindings)" will only add the last endpoint found.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of getting the browse url

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();
Site site = serverMgr.Sites["YourSiteName"];
List<string[]> urls = new List<string[]>();
foreach (Binding binding in site.Bindings)
{
    string bindingInfo = binding.BindingInformation;
    string subString = bindingInfo.Substring(2, bindingInfo.Length - 2);
    string[] adrs = subString.Split(':');
    adrs[0] = "localhost:" + adrs[0];
    urls.Add(adrs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JexusManager is now open source, so you can check its implementation of Binding.ToUri method,

https://github.com/jexuswebserver/Microsoft.Web.Administration/blob/master/Microsoft.Web.Administration/Binding.cs

```
        internal string ToUri()
        {
            var address = EndPoint.Address.Equals(IPAddress.Any)
                ? Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.HostName.ExtractName()
                : EndPoint.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                    ? EndPoint.Address.ToString()
                    : string.Format("[{0}]", EndPoint.Address);
            return IsDefaultPort
                ? string.Format("{0}://{1}", Protocol, address)
                : string.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}", Protocol, address, EndPoint.Port);
        }
```

As Microsoft's MWA does not expose the HostName part, you have to replace that with something equivalent (as you are the one who initialize ServerManager, you should know what is the host name).